# How to calculate song lengths in a spreadsheet?

Tags: cell-format

Good afternoon.  I'm using the LibreOffice Spreadsheet document to generate music logs for a broadcast assignment.  I'm unable to use the "time" "876613:37:46" to format the cells to calculate the track lengths.  Is there an alternate way to format the cells in order to get a total running time of the assignment?  Here's a sample show.

```
Column                                   Column             Column
  A                                        B                  C
Row 1 Title                              Artist             Length
Row 2 Opening Bed 2                                         00:1:15
Row 3 Commercial Break #1                                   00:2:00
Row 4 Outque Bed                                            00:0:05
Row 5 THE SOUND OF MUSIC              Billy Vaughn          00:2:36
Row 6 AUTUMN LEAVES                  Wout Steenhuis         00:3:45
Row 7 THIS GUY'S IN LOVE WITH YOU    Frank Chacksfield      00:2:49
Row 8 THE WAY WE WERE                 Roger Webb            00:4:01
Row 9 WHEN YOUR LOVER HAS GONE        Norrie Paramor        00:2:25
Row 10 WAVE                           Bert Kaempfert        00:3:19
Row 11 THEME FROM 'A SUMMER PLACE'     Joe Reisman          00:2:12
Row 12 BEWITCHED                       Ronnie Aldrich       00:3:17
Row 13 THERE'S A KIND OF HUSH         The Les Reed Sound    00:2:38
Row 14 Outque Bed                                           00:0:05
Row 15 Commercial Break #2                                  00:2:00
Row 16 Outque Bed                                           00:0:05
Row 17 RAINDROPS KEEP FALLING ON MY HEAD  Ron Goodwin       00:2:26
Row 18 LYIN' EYES                        Living Strings     00:3:39
Row 19 LIKE SOMEONE IN LOVE              Harold Bradley     00:2:53
Row 20 TOO BEAUTIFUL FOR WORDS             John Fox         00:3:16
Row 21 YOU ARE THE SUNSHINE OF MY LIFE      Manuel          00:3:30
Row 22 WHERE OR WHEN                      Cal Tjader        00:2:49
Row 23 EVERYTHING I HAVE IS YOURS       Michel Legrand      00:2:58
Row 24 STRANGERS IN THE NIGHT          Horst Jankowski      00:3:18
Row 25 Outque Bed                                           00:0:05
Row 26 Commercial Break #3                                  00:2:00
Row 27 Closing Bed                                          00:0:30

Row 29 Total Running Time:                                  00:00:00
```

I'm using Media Monkey to generate the playlist and then exporting it as a `.cvs` file.  I then open it with the LibreOffice software.
Thank you, Dan

Comment: You can create your own concatenated string always. Calculate seconds, minutes, hours, then put them altogether with &

Comment: What foes "876613:37:46" have to do with your question? Where does it come from?

Comment: What is actually contained in the raw data displayed in Col C?  Is it a text string in that format?

Comment: Hi Eric.  I'm not sure what a concatenated string is.  How do you create one?  Thanks, Dan

Comment: Hi David.  That's the setting type I selected when formatting the cells.  I read a post on a LibreOffice forum advising to use that setting.  Thanks, Dan

Comment: Hi Fixer1234.  The raw data is the track length on the playlist I exported from the Media Monkey software.  Thanks, Dan

Comment: Hi Cybernard.  Thank you very much for the explanation.  That corrected the times.  Have a great day, Dan

Comment: Hi Drakonoved.  Thank you for the help.  Cybernard's explanation did it.  Have a great day, Dan

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternate way to format the cells in order to get a total
>   running time of the assignment?

[image: Here is the correct formatting]

1. add 0's to make the second column 2 digits.

   Search and replace (CTRL H) find 00: replace with 00:0
2. Format the column as shown above.
3. =sum(c3:c99)

Done

[image: Working example]

This works because excel treats time as a number.  Numbers can simply be added together.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Summation of rows with time in format `hh:mm:ss`. LibreOffice

Do the following steps:

1. Split `Track Length` column `hh:mm:ss` to 3 separate columns: `Hours, Minutes, Seconds`.
2. Add fourth column `Track Length in seconds` and convert 3 previous columns to seconds:

   ```
   Hours * 60 * 60 + Minutes * 60 + Seconds = Track Length in seconds
   ```
3. Summarize all rows for new column, so you'll get `Total Tracks Length` (**`TTL`**) in seconds.
4. Convert `TTL` in seconds column to 3 separate columns: `Hours, Minutes, Seconds`:

   ```
   //Finding an integer number of Hours, Minutes and Seconds

   Hours = INT(TTL / 60 / 60)
   Minutes = INT((TTL - Hours * 60 * 60) / 60)
   Seconds = INT(TTL - Hours * 60 * 60 - Minutes * 60)
   ```
5. Join 3 separate columns to one time format column `hh:mm:ss`.

---

> **INT** *function* - rounds a number down to the nearest integer.

---

> It's intended that **TTL** in seconds is less then `86400` (one day long)

Answer (score 0):

For those who may be searching for the Excel formula to calculate a song length:

Formula:   **=60/(tempo/bpm)*measures/60***

Ex.

-Tempo is in cell B2.   Let's use 90 as our song tempo.

-BPM (top number in time signature) is in B3.   Let's use 3/4 as our time signature.

-Measures are in B4.   Let's use 144 as our number of measures.

In cell B5 enter the formula:  =60/(B2/B3)*B4/60

Formula Result: 4.80

In cell B6 enter the formula: =B5/24

Format cell B6 as Custom - h:mm

-The result is 4:48.

So, our song length is 4 minutes and 48 seconds.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149857)